# D3 heatmap convert code to use json instead of tsv

Tags: json, d3.js

I am trying to use D3 heatmap: http://bl.ocks.org/tjdecke/5558084 but had trouble changing the code. The example shows the use of .tsv files but I want to use .json file instead.

So instead of tsvFiles code as show below:

```
var heatmapChart = function(tsvFile) {
        d3.tsv(tsvFile,
        function(d) {
          return {
            day: +d.day,
            hour: +d.hour,
            value: +d.value
          };
        },
        function(error, data) {
          // eliminate code
        });  
      };
```

I tried changing to json (but it does not work):

```
d3.json("./data/data.json",
            function(d) {
                    return {
                        day: +d.day + 1,
                        hour: +d.hour + 1,
                        value: +d.value
                    };
                },

                function(error, data) {
                     // eliminate error
 });
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`d3.json` doesn't accept an accessor function, only `d3.csv` and `d3.tsv` accept it (the accessor function is that function between "data.json" and "function(error, data)" in your snippet).

So, change your `d3.json` function to:

```
d3.json("./data/data.json",  function(error, data) {
    //the rest of your code
});
```

And, in "the rest of your code", write the accessor function. In your case, something like this:

```
data.forEach(function(d) {
    return {
         day: +d.day + 1,
          hour: +d.hour + 1,
          value: +d.value
     };
 });
```

Also, this will only work if your JSON mimics exactly the  structure of the array of objects created by `d3.tsv`.