# how to read json file in d3 using pie chart?

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, d3.js

I am trying to make pie chart using `d3` `lib` .I tried first using `csv` file .It is working fine 
here is my code
https://plnkr.co/edit/GQVptaAULzHVRYsQCycG?p=preview

**But**
when I used `json` file instead of `csv` file it not show `pie` chart

here is my code
https://plnkr.co/edit/OYH6TYPPJgshaSzPbN1e?p=preview

```
d3.json("data.json", function(d) {
       // alert(d)
        d.population = +d.population;
        return d;
    }, function(error, data) {
        if (error) throw error;

        var arc = g.selectAll(".arc")
            .data(pie(data))
            .enter().append("g")
            .attr("class", "arc");

        arc.append("path")
            .attr("d", path)
            .attr("fill", function(d) { return color(d.data.age); });

        arc.append("text")
            .attr("transform", function(d) { return "translate(" + label.centroid(d) + ")"; })
            .attr("dy", "0.35em")
            .text(function(d) { return d.data.age; });
    });
```

**doc**

https://bl.ocks.org/mbostock/3887235

Comment: Also duplicate of this: http://stackoverflow.com/q/42475033/5768908 And this one too: http://stackoverflow.com/q/39831114/5768908

Answer (score 0):

Callback function for getting json was set differently (older style).

After I got the code to work I investigated and confirmed how callbacks were sent. On a good request without any errors passes (null, data). Bad request passes only (error)

Here's how it should look

```
d3.json("data.json", function(error, data) {
    if (error) throw error;

    var arc = g.selectAll(".arc")
        .data(pie(data))
        .enter().append("g")
        .attr("class", "arc");

    arc.append("path")
        .attr("d", path)
        .attr("fill", function(d) {
            return color(d.data.age);
        });

    arc.append("text")
        .attr("transform", function(d) {
            return "translate(" + label.centroid(d) + ")";
        })
        .attr("dy", "0.35em")
        .text(function(d) {
            return d.data.age;
        });
});
```